# SSRS and maps of route from data

Tags: excel, dictionary, reporting-services, routes

I have data that has the longitude and latitude values for a point of origin, stops and the return point of origin.

I'd like to be able to create a matrix that uses this information from an Excel spreadsheet and then have a map displayed with a line from the beginning to the end.

I can figure out how to create the matrix and group so that each route would be separated but how do I create the map with the route line?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified which version of SQL Server you use I've provided a link to an articles that date back to SQL 2008R2.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2552/creating-an-ssrs-map-report-with-data-pinpoints/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/convert-spatial-points-data-to-line-data-for-use-in-line-layer-in-sql-server-rep

The first deals with just getting stuff plotted on maps and the second looks more at how to draw lines between to points.

If you use an older version of SQL Server you may have to look to 3rd party options.